# QGIS crashes unexpectedly when using Raster Clip tool

Tags: raster, gdal, clip, qgis-2

Running QGIS 2.18 on Mac OS 10.14.
Python 2.7 and GDAL 2.1 installed.

Trying to clip raster by polygon (raster--> extraction --> clipper) I get error message: `qgis 2.18 clipper The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program*.`

Then QGIS crashes, gives the following message:

```
Process:               QGIS [4831]
Path:                  /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
Identifier:            org.qgis.qgis2
Version:               2.18.28 (2.18.28 [exported])
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           QGIS [4831]
User ID:               501
Date/Time:             2019-04-17 23:41:07.988 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.2 (18C54)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        920AA060-0540-B21D-7AD7-A6AF2928F792
Time Awake Since Boot: 4700 seconds
System Integrity Protection: enabled
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00003e10c0113cd0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [4831]
VM Regions Near 0x3e10c0113cd0:
    JS JIT generated code  0000249fa5400000-0000249fdd400000 [896.0M] rwx/rwx SM=NUL  reserved VM address space (unallocated)
--> 
    MALLOC_NANO            0000600000000000-0000600010000000 [256.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
```

What's going on? Why does raster clipper not work? More lines follow.